# Why is my Python class memoizing by default?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Context: I am running Python 2.7 (I am restricted to this version because reasons.)

I have a Python class, that looks something like this:

```py
class MyClient( object ):
    def __init__(self, my_dict):
        self.value = my_dict

    def run():
        # do some stuff and update self.value
```

In a Python shell, if I do:

```py
test_dict = {"foo": "bar"}
x = MyClient(test_dict).run()
y = MyClient(test_dict).run()
```

Y is a cached version of X! I know that it's returning a cached version because `self.value` is updated after by `run()`. When I do `y = MyClient(test_dict)`, the output shows me a value that would only appear if the code ran once before and updated `self.value`.

I haven't ever come across this behavior before... I'm not explicitly using a cache on any properties.

However, if I do:

```py
test_dict = {"foo": "bar"}
x = MyClient(test_dict)
y = MyClient({"foo": "bar"})
```

Y is NOT the cached version of X.

I'm wondering if the Python class is trying to be helpful by seeing that I initialized a class with the same object in memory, and returning the already existing one rather than creating a new one?

I have looked at some other SO questions, but all of them are related to implementing memoization in a Python class. I can't find anything about Python classes self-memoizing (which I believe is my issue here).

Comment: check `id` of both object and `self.value` in both

Comment: It's not cached. You're simply passing in the same mutable object and assigning it to `self.value`.

Comment: It all depends on what `run` actually does, which you haven't shared. If all it does is mutate the dictionary, then you can expect this behavior. It's got nothing to do with caching, or Python "trying to be helpful".

Comment: Could it be that you're expecting a statement like `self.value = my_dict` to make a deep copy of `my_dict`? Because that's not how it works. You're just binding `self.value` to the mutable object `my_dict`. Any mutations you perform on `self.value` will be reflected in the original object.

Comment: @PaulM.-- you're exactly correct. I thought that because it was an instance of a class, that `self.value = test_dict` would be a unique location in memory each time. I didn't realize it would hold the reference to the mutable object `test_dict`. Thank you!

Comment: Mandatory link to this [article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: It is not cached at all. *You simply wrote code that re-uses the same object*. Where did you think a *new object was created*? Stop thinking in terms of "memory locations", that is almost never the right level of abstraction for Python. Think in terms of objects. You created a dictionary object here: `test_dict = {"foo": "bar"}`. Nowhere else do you create a new dictionary object. You simply us the same one twice.

Answer (score 2):

The comment replies on my question provided the answer.

"It all depends on what run actually does, which you haven't shared. If all it does is mutate the dictionary, then you can expect this behavior. It's got nothing to do with caching, or Python "trying to be helpful"." -- [@Paul M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10987432/paul-m)

"You're simply passing in the same mutable object and assigning it to self.value" -- [@Axe319](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12479639/axe319)

--

Summary: My class mutated the dict that was passed on initialization. When I passed that dict the second time, it had already been mutated.

```py
test_dict = {"foo": "bar"}

x = MyClient(test_dict).run() # mutated the object in memory referenced by 'test_dict'

y = MyClient(test_dict).run() # test_dict was mutated by the above call
```

I thought that because I was creating an instance of a class, `self.value` would be unique to that particular instance, rather than holding a reference to the mutable dict passed on initialization. But that was a wrong assumption.